# How do MySQL aggregate sum function with two different data tables?

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate

[image: tbl_categories_quantity]

```
 SELECT
    category_id,
    product_size,
    category_name,
    SUM(product_quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM tbl_categories_quantity  -- (table-1)
INNER JOIN tbl_categories USING (category_id)
GROUP BY category_id,product_size
```

The Above Code is working in a single table, and I want to Add the below code (2nd table) that does not work

[image: tbl_product_sell]

```
SELECT
    category_id,
    product_size,
    SUM(product_sell) AS total_sell
FROM tbl_product_sell -- (table-2)
GROUP BY category_id,product_size;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Multiple value for category 1 where others value are unique. is it possible?

Comment: Additional screenshot added # Rahul Biswas

Comment: please check my below answer.

Comment: #Mr. Rahul Biswas your replay post is disappeared.

Comment: Is my post help you? Please check my query below.

Comment: # Mr. Rahul Biswas Opened tab link is working, Thanks Again and brilliant idea.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b8c54aa656d9dc930fcb7a93d2bc0960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **first** subquery retrieves category and product size wise total **quantity** and **second** one retrieves total **sales** based on category and product size. Then combine this two subquery with **LEFT JOIN** because sometimes sale may not happen. **COALESCE()** is used for replacing NULL value to 0 (zero). If specific category or product size wise data are required then use **WHERE** clause in both the subquery. As category id is unique so MAX(category_name) is used otherwise category name must be placed in GROUP BY clause. Subtract total sale from total quantity for **calculating** available quantity.

```
   -- MySQL
    SELECT t.category_name category
         , t.product_size
         , t.product_quantity
         , COALESCE(p.total_sell, 0) product_sell
         , (t.product_quantity - COALESCE(p.total_sell, 0)) available_in_stock
    FROM (SELECT tc.category_id
               , tcq.product_size
               , MAX(tc.category_name) category_name
               , SUM(tcq.product_quantity) product_quantity
          FROM tbl_categories tc
          INNER JOIN tbl_categories_quantity tcq
                  ON tc.category_id = tcq.category_id 
          GROUP BY tc.category_id
                 , tcq.product_size) t
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT category_id
                    , product_size
                    , SUM(product_sell) total_sell
               FROM tbl_stock_sell
               GROUP BY category_id
                      , product_size) p
           ON t.category_id = p.category_id
          AND t.product_size = p.product_size
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b8c54aa656d9dc930fcb7a93d2bc0960

**N.B.:** Table name or column name may vary based on your DB.

Comment: Error message #Rahul Biswas

Comment: please give me the error message. @MaungChang

Comment: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in

Comment: Any update regard this.

Comment: There are three tables and this is an aggregate function.
1. tbl_categories for Inner Join ( category Name)
2. tbl_categories_quantity for Product Quantity and Product size
3. tbl_product_sell table for calculating available stock
I will share screenshot.

Comment: I can not understand the scenario. I used your two queries and combine them. It's better to provide sample data with table structure and desired result.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @MaungChing if my answer helps you then mark it as accepted (green tick) along with upvote so that anyone can pick this without any doubt when searching related this.

Comment: @MaungChing any update for the above query. Please response if it's helped or not.

Comment: @ Rahul Biswas, It helps me very quickly after your quick responses, and yesterday my laptop keypad was service center and sorry for the late responses.
Thank you, Mr.Rahul Biswas.